# React Next Tailwind CSS - How to create a hyperlink around custom component

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, next.js, tailwind-css

In my index.tsx I have
`<Header/>`

In my Header.js component, I am using a HeroIcon embedded component.

```
    export default function Header() {
      return (
        <header className='flex flex-col sm:flex-row m-5 justify-between items-center h-auto'>
          <div className='flex flex-grow justify-evenly max-w-2xl'>
            <HeaderItem title='HOME' Icon={HomeIcon} />
            <HeaderItem title='ACCOUNT' Icon={UserIcon}  />
```

In my HeaderItem.js

```
    export default function HeaderItem({Icon,title}) {
      return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center cursor-pointer group w-12 sm:w-20
        hover:text-red">
            <Icon className="h-8 mb-1 group-hover:animate-bounce"/>
            <p className="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 tracking-widest"> {title} </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

As far as I understand, I can pass a ref from the Header to HeaderItem component via props and then use the Link tag.
How do I wrap that around without losing the animation?

Answer (score 0):

OK so this works for me -
On Header.js

```
 <HeaderItem title='HOME' Icon={HomeIcon} url="/"/>
```

On the HeaderItem.js

```
 export default function HeaderItem({Icon,title, url}) {                                         
      return (                                                                                      
      <Link href={url}>                                                                             
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center cursor-pointer group w-12 sm:w-20                
        hover:text-red">                                                                            
            <Icon className="h-8 mb-1 group-hover:animate-bounce"/>                                 
            <p className="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 tracking-widest"> {title} </p>          
                                                                                                    
        </div>                                                                                      
       </Link>                                                                                      
      )                                                                                             
    }
```